# SQL Server cascade on delete not working for two fk relations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `messageTable` with this structure:

```
id,
fromId,
toId,
text
```

and another table `profileTable` with these columns:

```
profileId,
name,
location
```

`profileId` is a foreign key referred to from the `messageTable` for the columns `fromId` and `toId`.

I want to add option for cascade rule on delete for both `fromId` and `toId`. But I get this error:

> 'Profile' table saved successfully
>   'Message' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_Message_Profile1'.
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Message_Profile1' on table 'Message' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I have tried in mysql, it's working fine there. But it is not working in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you please provide the script that you execute to generate that error?.

Comment: ON DELETE CASCADE, SET DEFAULT, or SET NULL cannot be defined if an INSTEAD OF trigger ON DELETE already exists on the table that is being altered. please check it once

Comment: Seems this is a limitation of SQL Server (works on Postgres and Oracle as well)